# page not found error when deploying the project(tango with django)

Tags: python, django

i've been learning django through the book "How to Tango with django". i tried to deploy my project on pythonanywhere.com, which is the suggested hosting in tango with django and luckily everything went well.but when i tried to run my domain, i am presented with an error of "Page not found". i then tried again but this time clonning the whole tango_with_django_17 project on my pythonanywhere account and when again i tried to run it, still the same error and it goes like this:

```
Using the URLconf defined in tango_with_django_project_17.urls,Django  tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^rango/
^accounts/register/$ [name='registration_register']
^accounts/
media/(?P<path>.*)

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

.. i am not able to figure out where is the problem. and here is my urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
def get_success_url(selfself,request, user):
    return '/rango/'


 urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
       #url(r'^$', 'tango_with_django_project_17.views.home', name='home'),
      #url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
     url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
 )

    if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


  if settings.DEBUG:
      urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static', (r'media/(?P<path>.*)', 'serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

can anybody plz help me here?

Comment: What is part of URL after `<your-account>.pythonanywhere.com` you entered?

Comment: It works, but you have problems with static files. Don't post your account name! You can edit comment.

Comment: okk..thanks..which file should i edit then to make it work, can you please tell?

Comment: If you want to see a page at `http://<your-account>.pythonanywhere.com/`, there needs to be something in your `urls.py` for the "root" URL -- that is, the URL where there is nothing after the domain name.  You have lines in your `urls.py` for `/admin/`, `/rango/`, `/accounts/register/`, and `/accounts/`, but you don't have one for `/`.  It will be a `url` line just like the others, but the first parameter will be `'^$'`

Comment: thanks man, i just added: url(r'^$', include('rango.urls')), and now it works all perfect..thanks to f43d65 and Giles Thomas..